# Set AUTO_INCREMENT value through variable in MySql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table with an auto_increment column. I save the last value of the column in another table called ids_tbl, and when mysql restarts, read the value from ids_tbl and re-set the AUTO_INCREMENT value.
If I do this:

```
alter table outgoing_tbl auto_increment=500;
```

it works

But if I do this

```
select @max_id:= max_id FROM ids_tbl;
alter table outgoing_tbl auto_increment=@max_id;
```

or if I do this:

```
select @max_id:= max_id FROM ids_tbl;
alter table outgoing_tbl auto_increment=(select @max_id);
```

Then it does not work, how do I set the auto increment value throgh a variable?

Comment: One option is to use a [13.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: FWIW, the need for this is going away in MySQL 8.0. See http://lefred.be/content/bye-bye-bug-199/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the below code. This is working fine.
And follow the MySQL prepared statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

```
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM `ids_tbl` );
SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `outgoing_tbl` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @max_id);
PREPARE st FROM @sql;
EXECUTE st;
```

Comment: Thank you. That was great. Thank you @Bill Karwin, I will think about an upgrade too.

Comment: Except you might want to increment the @max_id by 1:    

    `SELECT MAX(id) + 1 INTO @max_id FROM ids_tbl;`

Comment: Thank you for this great solution