# Procedure to change auto_increment value on table

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

I want write procedure which after execute another procedure change auto increment value in my table. Problem is procedure created ,but not works. When i try to run i have error #1210 - Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE. I find similar problem in link : [Set AUTO_INCREMENT value through variable in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622690/set-auto-increment-value-through-variable-in-mysql) ,but it's not working for me.

I try change @v_value for v_value (normal variable, not @variable). Also I try use '?' in @v_sql but not working too. I try change 'READS SQL DATA' but no matter. Help what's going wrong.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE check_increment_value()
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
SET @v_value = (SELECT MAX(id_version)+1 FROM versions);
SET @v_sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `wersje` AUTO_INCREMENT = ',@v_value);
PREPARE st FROM @v_sql;
EXECUTE st USING @v_value;
END
//
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set AUTO\_INCREMENT value through variable in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622690/set-auto-increment-value-through-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: Just follow the code in the linked answer **exactly**. There is no argument to `EXECUTE` in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the parameter via string interpolation, not via the prepared statement, so you do not need to specify the `using` clause:

```
EXECUTE st;
```