# How to adjust unique identifier when dropping a row

Tags: php, sql, database, auto-increment

I have a table that stores users. I have been making new accounts to test registration and login functionality, but when I drop a row, the ID keeps incrementing (set to auto increment), so right now I have ID 1,2, and 9. When it's only a few, it's not a big deal, but over time I feel like that could be an issue. What is the best way to deal with that? Should I look for empty ID's and force new users into that slot or when a user deletes their account should I adjust the table? Is there a simple built in function to deal with this? I feel like this should be a common enough issue that there should be something for it.

Comment: This is standard behavior. You should build your application so that it never expects auto-increment ids to be sequential and you should NEVER re-use auto-increment ids

Comment: An [int](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) type can store 2 billion + ids. You're probably not going to run out if that is what is worrying you.

Comment: Also of note, generally speaking, best practice is to never delete users at all, but rather to have an "active" column with 1 for active and 0 for not. This way we dont break relationships that user might have had with other records in the db

Comment: @WesleySmith Can be challenging if user profiles contain personally identifying data, like email address, name etc. As regulators crack the privacy issue (GDPR, new CA laws), keeping data that you don't need becomes a liability, not an asset. Even with soft-delete, make sure that you properly clean them up of any identifying / pseudo-identifying data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanna do that (**but don't do it**), you can do this:

```
SET @max_id = (SELECT MAX(`id`) + 1 FROM `mytable` );
SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `mytable` AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @max_id);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

It will search for the max id from your table and set the auto increment to this id

***Source***: [Set AUTO_INCREMENT value through variable in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622690/set-auto-increment-value-through-variable-in-mysql)